# char* to NSData issue

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I am trying to write a function that takes `char*` as an input parameter and will serialize it into JSON.

I am running into an issue with converting the input parameter, `options` to NSData. I used the following line of code:

`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:options length:sizeof(options)];`

This did not work. A different set of code did work:

`NSString* stringFromChar = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:options];
NSData * data = [stringFromChar dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

I am curious about why it was necessary to convert my code from `char*` to an NSString and then to NSData and why I could not do that directly. Is there a way to directly convert `char*` to NSData without this intermediary step? Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof(options)` is most likely not what you expect it to be. Use a `NSLog` to output that value. Or add some more code to give the question more context.

Comment: Look at the documentation for strlen().

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicated, `sizeof(options)` where `options` is a `char *` will produce the size of the pointer, not the length of the string.  Also pointed out in comments, `strlen(options)` counts characters up to the first 0x0, which is what you want...

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:options length:strlen(options)];
// options must be null-terminated
```